# How can I suppress notifications, such as Amber alerts, on Android 11?

Tags: notifications, android-11

How can I suppress notifications, such as Amber alerts, on Android 11? I am getting numerous alerts for which I can do nothing, but my peace is being interrupted by these irrelevant alerts.

Answer (score 1):

On the Home Screen, swipe up to show the list of installed Apps, search for "Messages" and open the "Messages" app.

Tap the 3 vertical dots "..." next to the magnifying glass (upper-right corner of the screen) and select "Settings".

Select "Emergency alert settings"
Select "Emergency alerts"

You can now uncheck "Extreme alerts", "Severe alerts", and "AMBER alerts".

---

*Verified on Android 9, but provided here in the hope it will be helpful to others, as these steps are somewhat arcane, and searching in settings yields no results.*

Answer (score 0):

Open Setttings -> Notifications -> Wireless emergency alerts, set `AMBER alerts` to off.

Assuming you are using Google Messages:

1. Press the profile, then Messages settings.
2. Press Advanced -> Wireless emergency alerts. Press the 3-dots, select Alert preferences.
3. Emergency alerts opens. Set `AMBER alerts` to off. Or you can just switch off `Allow alerts`.

Optionally, you can also switch off `Extreme threats` and `Severe threats`.

Answer (score 0):

The exact method will vary by device, but the general steps are:

1. Go to the Settings app
2. Select "Apps & notifications", or your device's equivalent category containing notification preferences.
3. Select "Wireless emergency alerts", which may be under Advanced.
4. Toggle the alerts that you wish to receive on/off.

Alternatively, if your OEM moved the category for the alerts, you can use the settings app's search bar to search for "Wireless emergency alerts".